# Returning sub attributes in Rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb, reql

Given this document:

```
{
"Country": {
"ISO-3166-1-Alpha-2":  "AD" ,
"ISO-3166-1-Alpha-3":  "AND" ,
"ISO-3166-1-Numeric": 20 ,
"ISO-3166-2":  "ISO 3166-2:AD" ,
"LongNames": {
"en-us":  "Andorra"
} ,
"ShortNames": {
"en-us":  "Andorra"
} ,
"WebName":  "Andorra"
} ,
"id":  "AD"
}
```

What would the right query to return just `WebName` ?

I've tried using Map(), but the results aren't what I expect:

`r.db("main").table("countries").limit(1).map(function(r) {
  return r.WebName;
});`

```
RqlDriverError: Anonymous function returned `undefined`. Did you forget a `return`?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, `(...)` is the field selector.

```
r.db("main").table("countries").limit(1)('Country')('WebName')
```

Comment: `r.db("main").table("countries").limit(1)('Country')('WebName')` Worked.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I missed the nested field 'Country'